# Using shape builder tool on a pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I created an asphalt-like pattern in Illustrator so I can create a street. I followed a tutorial to make the street pattern, and the shading goes up and down. So I distorted the image so it goes at an angle, to be consistent with the perspective in the image. However, the image now goes partially off the artboard. So I put a frame around it and tried to use the shape tool to trim off the excess bit of the street. But when I do that, the pattern remaining changes. Is there a way around this? I hope I'm explaining this well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just create a path which covers all the areas you want to keep, and then create a clipping mask.

Make your clipping path on top, select all the paths and **Right click → Make Clipping Mask** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>).

The good thing with a *Clipping Mask* is that it's non-destructive, meaning you can easily make changes and fix things.